# Add buttons more buttons

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am trying to put more than button but its not functioning:

```
    View scanbarcode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanbarcode);
    View facility = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facility);   

    // For Scan bar code
    scanbarcode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CameraPreviewActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

    // For facility menu 
    facility.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FacilityActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: if {(You get a crash, please show us the logcat output)} else {(please tell us what is not working)}

Comment: facility button is not functioning

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but I have to show the code. What about if you change the View into a Button:

```
       Button scanbarcode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanbarcode);
       Button facility = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facility);   

       // For Scan bar code
      scanbarcode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),CameraPreviewActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);   

         }

           });

       // For facility menu 
         facility.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FacilityActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);   
    }
  });
```

This should work. Apart from that, do you really need to reference the Buttons to the right layout.xml? Could You please show us the layout.xml file?

Comment: <Button android:id="@+id/scanbarcode" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" android:text="Scan Barcode" android:title="@string/legalnotes" android:color="#e0e2e3"/>  <Button android:id="@+id/facility"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:color="#e0e2e3"
            android:text="Other Facilities"/>

Comment: what I mean was, to say it short: Please show us the whole Activity, or let us know which layout You referenced in setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); and post the whole xml layout with the name saved in your project

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewer);

Comment: and how is this xml layout where the button that You´ve showed above is inside called? Is this the same layout? Sometimes it happens that newbies try to reference a button from the wrong layout, that´s why I am asking.